# Проблемы с urlrewrite в битрикс

Tags: битрикс, url, чпу

Пытаюсь настроить urlrewrite в битриксе для того чтобы страница отвечала по другим адресам.И необходимо реализовать это с вложенностью и динамически. В первом правиле необходимо чтобы итоговый url был /ru/{название_города_который_выбрал_юзер}/services/ , а во втором просто /ru/{название_города_который_выбрал_юзер}/ . Почему то сейчас обрабатывается только второй случай и вызывается только та физическая страница которую я указал в PATH. В чем может быть проблема?

```
    $arUrlRewrite=array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/ru/([a-zA-Z_-]*)/services/#',
    'RULE' => 'SECTION_CODE=$1',
    'ID' => '',
    'PATH' => '/ru/services/index.php',
  ),
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/ru/#',
    'RULE' => 'SECTION_CODE=$1',
    'ID' => '',
    'PATH' => '/ru/index.php',
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

правильный ответ

```
'CONDITION' => '#^/ru/([a-zA-Z_-]*)/services#',
```